# Xamarin Forms Login Button Animation

Tags: xamarin, animation, authentication, xamarin.forms, lottie

I've created a login page with XAML in Xamarin Forms similar to the one in the gif. Now I want to animate the button like in the example. I never animated anything in Xamarin Forms so I have no clue how to get a transition like that. Can anyone explain me how I can get the button to shrink to a circle and become a loading animation?

The button currently looks like this:

```
<Button Text="Login" Style="{StaticResource LoginFormButton}" />

<!-- LoginFormButton is defined in App.xaml -->
       <Style x:Key="LoginFormButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{ StaticResource bgColor }" />
            <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="25" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
        </Style>
```

[image: Login Animation]

Comment: You cannot do this kind of animation directly in Xamarin Forms, you will have to do it natively!

Comment: Check this link similar button animation is there you can use this. https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is possible to do this with Xamanimation, I am not sure if it is the best way. Another possibility is to use an animation and I would recommend Lottie.

If you are going to use Xamanimation

```
    xmlns:xamanimation="clr-namespace:Xamanimation;assembly=Xamanimation"

    <ContentPage.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>                
                <xamanimation:StoryBoard x:Key="Animation1"
                                         Target="{x:Reference Button1}">
                    <xamanimation:FadeToAnimation Opacity="1" Duration="1500" Easing="Linear"/>
                    <xamanimation:FadeToAnimation Opacity="0" Duration="1500" Easing="Linear"/>
                </xamanimation:StoryBoard>
                <xamanimation:StoryBoard x:Key="Animation2"
                                         Target="{x:Reference Button1}">
                    <xamanimation:FadeToAnimation Opacity="1" Delay="3000" Duration="1500" Easing="Linear"/>
                    <xamanimation:FadeToAnimation Opacity="0" Duration="1500" Easing="Linear"/>
                </xamanimation:StoryBoard>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

the component must be named

```
<Button x:Name="Button1"
        Opacity="0"/>
```

and need to include this in the codebehind

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            if (Resources["Animation1"] is StoryBoard storyBoardText1)
                storyBoardText1.Begin();
            if (Resources["Animation2"] is StoryBoard storyBoardText2)
                storyBoardText2.Begin();
            base.OnAppearing();
        }
```

Or you can use Lottie

https://lottiefiles.com/featured

https://lottiefiles.com/1894-submit-check-mark

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't do that in Xamarin Forms with just a button.
It would require a couple of more elements you have to add to your page. Then you can use Xamarin's built in animation system to adapt the element's dimensions and activate/deactivate their IsVisible properties during the course of your animation.

However here is how I would do it:

1. Insert a grid with 1 row and 1 column where your button is supposed to be
2. Place the button in that grid
3. Add an activity indicator into the grid
4. Add a CircleView into the grid (you have to derive from a BoxView and use a custom renderer to make it have rounded corners). Make sure that that CircleView has the same dimensions as your activity indicator

Now set IsVisible to false for the activity indicator and the CircleView.
After your login button was clicked, you can set the button's text to an empty string and use a custom animation (see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/custom ) to animate down either the width or the left and right margin of your button until it has narrowed down so far that its rounded corners form a circle and match the size of the activity indicator.

You can use the custom animation's finished delegate to set the IsVisible property for the button to false and for the activity indicator to true.

As soon as your login procedure (i suppose you will send some kind of request and consume the data from the response) is done, set IsVisible for your activity indicator to false, for the circleview to true and then use another custom animation to animate the width and the height of the circleview.

Also make sure that the IsClippedToBounds property of your grid is set to false, because else the circle view will not be able to grow outside of it's containing grid.

Comment: I'll check this out. Thank you for your answer!